# How to download all intraday data at one time

Tags: data-request, finance

Is there any way to download all available intraday data for stocks at once (for example, all the data available at the Indian stock exchange)? I need to make a comparative analysis and downloading the data by ticker is too time consuming, besides I want to know if there is any website that store the historical intraday data. Other sites delete the data gradually.